# Significant change over NxM distributions

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have 100 sets of data, each of which consists of ~ 15 distributions along time, I've attached a figure of 1 of these sets to hopefully clear up what I mean. The plot shows the 95% confidence intervals and quartiles for each distribution, the red dot and line are actually irrelevant for this particular statistical test.

[image]

I want to determine for each of these sets whether or not between any two distributions, there is a significant difference. I originally considered the Kolmogorov Smirnov test, but for a reason I can't remember now (which is frustrating me and I'm sure frustrating you too), that isn't applicable. I've been considering the z test as outlined here: http://homework.uoregon.edu/pub/class/es202/ztest.html but i'm not sure if it is the best approach.

I also want to somehow be able to quantify the amount of sets of data across the 100 that contain significant difference, but not sure on how to do that yet (any ideas for that are most welcome).

Thank you very much

Comment: It all depends on what these data mean.  For instance, is there any prospect that the distribution at one time might not be independent of all the other distributions?  If not, you may be in a classic ANOVA situation; if so, then you need to provide much more information about *how* those dependencies might arise.

Comment: Hi whuber. 

I'm estimating phase between two signals every 60 seconds (I use 5 minute long chunks of larger recordings for each phase, so there is some overlap every time), and then generating simulations based on this value using a parametric bootstrap method to create distributions I can get confidence intervals from. So I think they aren't entirely independent? I'm not that great with statistics (or explaining things haha)

Comment: That's pretty vague, but the 60 second-5 minute numbers suggest the possibility of strong dependencies.  That's such a serious complication that, instead of trying to work out a valid statistical procedure to analyze these data, you might want to reconsider the entire approach and start all over by formulating the practical question you are trying to address and describing what data you have (or can potentially obtain).

Comment: How could I overcome this complication, using the same approach. I am able to modify the interval rather flexibly, I have 18 minute long recordings and simply use 60 seconds to get a reasonable number of distributions. Do you think an interval of perhaps 2.5 minutes would be better, or even no overlap? I would prefer to have some overlap to ensure I don't miss any of the data (aka if I did no overlaps would be 0-5, 5-10, 10-15 so missing 3 minutes). Thank you for your help by the way

Comment: I am reluctant to comment, being ignorant of the details, but having no overlap would likely improve the situation.  The distributions might still be interdependent due to serial correlation, though, which is why it's important to know the details.

Comment: Details in a summarised form that fits here:


Assessing autoregulation in the brain using FFT to extract phase between pressure and flow recordings (18 minutes long)


Using 5 minute chunks at a time, get phase, use a parametric bootstrap to simulate signals to get 200 more estimates i use to generate confidence intervals


Want to assess significant difference between distributions to determine whether autoregulation improves or deteriorates.


Trying to think of other details that might be relevant but I can't sorry :(


Ill try no overlap and see how it looks, using ANOVA?

Comment: I'm not seeing the point of the bootstrap: why don't you compare the actual data you have?

Comment: It's difficult to be able to determine how robust estimates of autoregulation are, due to the amount of data needed and it not being a very repeatable test (without going too much into that side of things, it's hard to make tests we use to get recordings work the same way twice). 

So we are stuck with only one recording per session, and no way to know how robust it is. The red line in the original figure is the true phase estimates obtained throughout time for one individual, and the boxplots = bootstrap confidence intervals.

The idea is these confidence intervals can indicate robustness

Comment: That seems like it obscures, rather than reveals, the data (in an extremely computationally intensive manner). If you are concerned about obtaining robust estimates, then use robust estimators.